# Can I get sound from only right/left earphone with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

When I play a sound with js, I just want the sound coming from the right. how can I do that

Comment: Do let us know, whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Check out [`StereoPannerNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StereoPannerNode) from the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API).

> The pan property takes a unitless value between -1 (full left pan) and
> 1 (full right pan). This interface was introduced as a much simpler
> way to apply a simple panning effect than having to use a full
> PannerNode.

Also see this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API#Adding_stereo_panning_to_our_app:

```
const pannerOptions = { pan: 0 };
const panner = new StereoPannerNode(audioContext, pannerOptions);
```

```
<input type="range" id="panner" min="-1" max="1" value="0" step="0.01">
```

```
const pannerControl = document.querySelector('#panner');

pannerControl.addEventListener('input', function() {
    panner.pan.value = this.value;
}, false);
```

```
track.connect(gainNode).connect(panner).connect(audioContext.destination);
```

(Note: this isn't specific to Vue)

Comment: example here: https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/stereo-panner-node